# BCC trackers Clients Marketing CLoud

Tags: marketing-cloud

Hello Everyone is there a way that we can track BCC in Marketing cloud I need this for the tracking of the clients part

Answer (score 0):

There is likely a standard report that includes the value for this setting somewhere, but your best bet is to use SQL Query activities and pull data from the [_Job Data View.](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/automation_studio/using_automation_studio_activities/using_the_query_activity/data_views/data_view_job/)

There is a field in this Data View labeled 'BccEmail', and it's value is described as

> Any email address send in the BCC field

Just first create a Data Extension to hold any data the client would find relevant, and then you can run the query from within automation studio to populate the Data Extension with this information.